# How can I dynamically output each index in an array to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

I'm attempting to create a tooltip that prints every indexed position of a particular array dynamically.

I first start with a 'for' loop that pushes the targeted values that I want displayed in the tooltip to an array if they pass a condition like so:

```
var myArray = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < ccirdata.length; i++) {
                if (myArray[i].catType === 'I') {       
                    myArray.push(ccirdata[i].catNum);

                }
            }
```

I'd like to iterate/print EACH index item of the array:

```
scope.data = [
                {
                    key: 'Category I',
                    MyAttribute:<INSERT HERE>
                },
```

So that my tooltip is formatted as such where 'MyAttribute' will create a new row, "< tr >" for every index item:

```
                       var header =
                                "<thead>" +
                                "<tr>" +
                                "<td class='legend-color-guide'><div style='background-color: " + series.color + ";'></div></td>" +
                                "<td class='key'>" + series.key + " CCIRs:</td>" +
                                "</tr>" +
                                "</thead>";

                            var rows =
                                "<tr>" +
                                "<td class='key'><strong>" + series.key + "</strong></td>" +
                                "<td class='x-value'>" + MyAttribute + "</td>" +
                                "</tr>" 

                            return "<table>" +
                                header +
                                "<tbody>" +
                                rows +
                                "</tbody>" +
                                "</table>";
```

I'm just not sure how this can be done, since iterations require javascript, and i'm looking to print each item in html format (the tooltip)

Comment: $('#outputTable').html(theFunction())  where theFunction() is the function you have there in your second block?  Can be done in pure js also if needed.

Comment: Is this vanilla JS or are you using any frameworks? If vanilla you need to use JS to create the HTML then insert it into the DOM. I would recommend using an MV* framework like angular or ember to allow you to create a dynamic UI.

Comment: @nurdyguy thanks for the response, could you please elaborate in the answers?

Comment: Well, you already have the string built out.  You'll need a table element to put the rows into.  If there is one already on the page then use that and replace '#outputTable' with the jQuery selector for your table.  If not then you'll need some sort of container, a place where you want the data to show up.  Can you post the html?